# Anuglar Format ViewModel of Input without changing model Value

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-ngmodel

Is there a clean way to change the ViewModel of an Input without changing the modelValue?

Example:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="myIban">
```

After every 4 chars I want to add a sperator.

ViewValue in the textfield: 1234 5678 9012 3456

ModelValue should be: 1234567890123456

I know I just could use **Regex** to replace the seperators at submitting, but I would prefer a directive or pipe or something else on the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply pipes directly to `[(ngModel)]` declaration because of Angular restrictions
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-statements

But you can breaks it into property+event binding:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="myIban | applySeparatorsPipe" 
      (ngModelChange)="myIban=$event" />
```

So you can implement `applySeparatorsPipe` then with formatting input sprint into string with separators.

Comment: I did it after holidays in that way you described it, but this solution will also change the model-value itself. I am looking for a clean solution where just the View-Value in the field is transformed but not the value of the model itself.